# angular hybrid app, lazy loaded module does not work when page refreshed

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

I have an angular hybrid app (angularjs with angular) with lazy loading on one of the feature modules.

The feature module is declared the following way

```
const contactFs: NgHybridStateDeclaration = {
    name: 'contact.v2.**',
    url: '/contact/v2/',
    loadChildren: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "contactM" */ './contacts.module').then(m => m.contactsModule)
};
```

I have the following states declared in the contacts module

```
export const state1: Ng2StateDeclaration = {
    name: 'contact.v2',
    url: '/'
};

export const state2: Ng2StateDeclaration = {
    name: 'contact.v2.details',
    url: ':id/details',
    component: detailsComponent,
};
```

Now I can navigate to the `contact.v2.details` state without a problem from the home component.  The url becomes something like `host/contact/v2/9ee34d65-a91f-460c-9947-e2a7ee9d5538/details`

The problem is that when the user clicks the refresh on the browser, it does not load the component, it just loads an empty state.  Not sure what is going wrong here, it seems like it is not loading the lazy loaded module at all when hitting the refresh button.

Comment: was this problem solved ?

Comment: `<base href='/'>` should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change in your **index.html** as below.

`<base href='./'>`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is when you refresh you don't have the data (in your first call you pass the data to the detail components but when you refresh the data are not in it)
you need to use rxjs and do the call on the onInit method (i say this because i am writing same project as you using drupal 8.9)